# In Endeca I want to have dgraph backups saved on dgraph server automatically after baseline update.

Tags: endeca

How to have 3 dgraphs backup saved automatically in dgraph server and not on ITL server . By default backup of dgidx output gets saved on ITL server . I want it to be saved on dgraph server ie MDEX host. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there to be an Out-of-the-Box option for backing up the deployed dgidx output on the target server. Have you gone through the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35851_03/PlatformServices.613/pdf/EACGuide.pdf)? I would also question whether it is a good idea. Consider you are deploying and 2 of the 3 servers have gone through successfully but the third one fails. You now need to roll back only two of the machines. Your central EAC will not know which ones to rollback and which ones to keep. However, by keeping it all at a central point (ie. on the ITL server) in the event of a rollback you will always push the same backup out to all three servers.

Assuming that you are trying to speed up the deployment of very large indices (Endeca copies the entire dgidx output to each MDEX), you can always look at the  [performance tuning guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28910_01/MDEX.622/pdf/PerfTuningGuide.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in any number of ways:

1. In any baseline update, dgidx_output is automatically copied to each
   dgraph server.  You should be  add a copy or archive job as a
   [pre-shutdown](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40177_03/ToolsAndFrameworks.312/pdf/DeploymentTemplateUsageGuide.pdf#_OPENTOPIC_TOC_PROCESSING_d0e4961) task for your dgraph.
2. You could also create a custom copy job that would for each dgraph
   server that would run at the end or beginning of a baseline update. 
   Or it could be offline from your baseline update entirely.

To a point radimpe makes, making copies on the dgraph servers is not that hard, but rather, it's the rollback process you need to really consider.  You need to set that up and ensure it uses whatever backup copies you've made, whether local to the ITL machine or on the dgraph servers.

Also know that dgidx_output will not include any partial update information added since the index was created.  Partial update info only be available in the dgraph_input on the dgraph servers.  Accordingly, if you incorporate partial updates, you should archive the dgraph input and make that available for any rollback job.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DGRAPH post startup task and assign it in the graph definitions.  It will will be executed on each MDEX startup

```
<dgraph id="Dgraph01" host-id="LiveMDEXHost01" port="10000" pre-shutdown-script="DgraphPreShutdownScript" post-startup-script="DgraphPostStartupScript">

 <script id="DgraphPostStartupScript">
    <bean-shell-script>
      <![CDATA[
...code to backup here
   ]]>
    </bean-shell-script>
  </script>
```